# no preemption victims found for incoming pod

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have multiple pods in multiple namespaces and all the pods are failing because of below error. I am just managing this environment and have no idea how this was done previously. How can I find out the reason for these failures and how to troubleshoot. Any help will be really appreciated here.

0/5 nodes are available: 5 too many pods. preemption: 0/5 nodes are available: 5 no preemption victims found for incoming pod.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).